# Kentico 11 - Macro's not working in Marketing Emails

Tags: kentico

I have just started to use Kentico, so far everything has been straight-forward however I cannot get certain Macro's to work in Marketing Emails (to insert personalized information in the email such as their country).

Here is a quick overview of my automation process

- Person submits a form on the website
- Form field information gets mapped to the contact
- Automation process begins

  - Internal/Transactional email sent which contains the requesters information (Macro's work)
  - Marketing email sent to requester, containing relevant information (Only basic Macro's work (for example recipient.firstname))

The issue is that the Macro's that are used (and working) in the internal transactional email do not appear to work in the marketing emails section, for example: {% OnlineMarketingContext.CurrentContact.ContactCountry #%} would copy in the requesters Country in the transactional/internal email, but it remains blank in marketing emails (Note: I have tested this fully, not as a draft email as I've read that the information doesn't get passed in a draft email).

I have tried using different objects (ContactManagementContext, etc.), however nothing appears to bring in personalized information.

Is there something I need to do to get the Macro's working within the Marketing Emails section? I have read through the docs online and I can't find anything to make this work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The newsletter email macros are based off the subscriber not the contact.  If you want to use the contact info, you will have to find a way to relate the subscriber to the contact.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=27&v=XFjR2C1k1KA) shows how to see what macros are available.

Answer (score 0):

Zach is correct. Normally, you would lookup the Contact based on the email address of the Recipient, e.g. `{%GlobalObjects.Contacts.Where("ContactEmail = '"+Recipient.Email+"'").TopN(1).FirstItem%}`. However, there is a hidden object you can use in marketing emails: `{%Advanced.ContactInfo%}`

Comment: Hi @EricD, thanks for your response, this is exactly what I needed and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad it helped :) Please upvote any answers that helped, and mark the solution... I need the reputation on this account as it's very new :)